# How do I make one thread Kill another?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

How can I make one thread kill another?

Here is an example code,

1- Start t1

2 - Start t2

3 - Once t2 is done. Kill t1 with t3

There are possibilities that I am completely confused and messing big time. :-)
Please advise if that is the case, also what method I should follow instead of what I am doing now. Thanks.

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
import time
import threading
import sys


def task():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    ft = ttk.Frame()
    ft.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)
    pb_hD = ttk.Progressbar(ft, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')
    pb_hD.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)
    pb_hD.start(10)
    root.mainloop()


def destroy():
    global t1
    # here it should be something like t1.kill()

def process_of_unkown_duration():
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'Done'

def Main():
    t1=threading.Thread(target=task,args=())
    t2=threading.Thread(target=process_of_unkown_duration,args=())
    t3=threading.Thread(target=destroy,args=())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
    t3.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to create three or even two threads. Just run the mainloop in the main thread, and create one thread to do the background task that kills the mainloop, by passing the `root` object to the background thread, and calling `root.quit()`.

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
import time
import threading
import sys


def task(root):
    ft = ttk.Frame()
    ft.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)
    pb_hD = ttk.Progressbar(ft, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')
    pb_hD.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)
    pb_hD.start(10)
    root.mainloop()

def process_of_unkown_duration(root):
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'Done'
    root.quit()

def Main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    t1=threading.Thread(target=process_of_unkown_duration, args=(root,))
    t1.start()
    task(root)  # This will block while the mainloop runs
    t1.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Thanks Dano, I tried your first option before, and it didnt work giving RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

But the second option just works great :-) Thanks a tonn

Comment: @Md.Mohsin Interesting. I didn't hit that exception on my Windows machine running Python 2.7. Anyway, the second option is a superior solution anyway. I accepted your edit removing the first option.

Comment: I see.. But your 2nd option is indeed superior. Thanks again dano, I truly appreciate it  :-)